# Question for domain diagram for optimizing course scheduling

Tags: optaplanner

I'm working on an optimization solution for a school that needs to schedule six courses into six periods that work for multiple students. Each student has selected/requested six courses, and the courses need to be scheduled into each period such that each student can receive their requested courses

I've looked into Optaplanner's design pattern guidelines as well as a couple examples and here's what I've created to model the domain of this problem.

[Domain Model Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhRSb.png)

If possible, I'd like some feedback or suggestions for whether or not this domain model is suitable for this specific problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, I think the domain model diagram you shared could work, with a couple of changes:

1. I would get rid of the bi-directional relationships expressed by the arrows: `CourseAssignment` has a reference to `Student` and `Course`, but there is no need for the opposite relations.
2. `CourseAssignment` is the `PlanningEntity` and thus, only this class has the `PlanningVariable` fields (`student` and `period`).
3. The `PlanningVariable` `requestedCourses` won't work; the `Student` class is not a `PlanningEntity` and requests are not what you want OptaPlanner to assign; the course assignments are. I would model the students' requests by a separate class `CourseRequest`. As a result, you will be able to use every request as a standalone fact in your constraints.
4. Do not forget to add the [problem fact collection properties](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#problemFacts) to the `CourseSchedule`.